# Python newbie question : Why the data is not displayed after executing the code

Tags: python

```
def Person_Info(Age,Work,Sex):

 Person_Info(21,"Java","male")

 Person_Info(24, "C", "male")

 Person_Info(31, "Java", "female")

 print("Age " + Age, + Work + "work " + Sex + "sex ")
```

Guys, if it's not hard for someone, please explain why when I execute the code, nothing happens. there is not even a "Nulled" value. I know that this is a newbie question..
It seems to me that 3 lines with the data that are specified in the Person_Info function should have been displayed. = / But nope

Comment: Are you calling this function somewhere? Perhaps you would like to post a [mre].

Comment: @khelwood If they did, they'd get a recursion error message rather than nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. What are you expecting to happen exactly? There are at least 4 problems in your code (function not called, infinite recursion, trying to join str and int, extra plus sign). Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Guys thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this

```
def Person_Info(Age, Work, Sex):
    print(f"Age={Age}, Work={Work}, Sex={Sex} ")
    
Person_Info(21, "Java", "male")
Person_Info(24, "C", "male")
Person_Info(31, "Java", "female")
```

Output

```
Age=21, Work=Java, Sex=male 
Age=24, Work=C, Sex=male 
Age=31, Work=Java, Sex=female
```

Comment: If you're gonna write `=` signs, you might as well make it shorter: `print(f"{Age=}, {Work=}, {Sex=}")`

Comment: Yes, but in the output the string will come in quotes @superbrain

Comment: Ah, indeed. I had actually tested it and visually compared with the output of yours, but apparently overlooked that. Then again, might actually be helpful, just like your added `=` signs (and your added commas).

Comment: @superbrain Along with that this convention is only available from python 3.8